# Django-tables2, Django-filters how to override .empty_text

Tags: python, django, django-tables2, django-filters

Hope everyone is well.

I'm using django-tables2 and django-filters to display large datasets in html tables.

I wanted to use the django-tables empty_text to return a message when there is zero results.

However I currently load the tables with an empty queryset to avoid large load times (Better to let the user decide if they want to generate the whole data set), this causes a problem because the empty_text message populates.

I want to know if there is a away to stop the empty_text message appearing if there is no filters applied or no filter URL.

If I can't do it that way maybe there is a better way to determine empty set on filter result.

Thanks in advance,

Thomas